# How to uninstall OpenVPN Access Server?

Tags: apt, server, uninstall, vpn, openvpn

I need to remove OpenVPN Access Server completely from my system. I installed it with root access(`sudo -i`) using the following commands from the OpenVPN website:

```
apt update && apt -y install ca-certificates wget net-tools gnupg
wget -qO - https://as-repository.openvpn.net/as-repo-public.gpg | apt-key add -
echo "deb http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian bionic main">/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list
apt update && apt -y install openvpn-as
```

There are unfortunately no clear instructions on how to remove the program and all the associated things installed with it. Can someone guide me on how to go about this?

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge openvpn-as`